# MySQL UPDATE query with two WHERE clauses not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that isnt working for some reason:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET displayname = 'test', member = '5'
WHERE username = 'testuser' AND password = 'testpass';
```

However, follow working fine:-

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET displayname = 'test', member = '5'
WHERE username = 'testuser';
```

How do I make update query based on these two where clauses??

Comment: Seems like testuser's password isn't testpass.

Comment: you have no rows to update

Comment: But there is, here is a real example: https://i.imgur.com/ctx7og1.png

Comment: it it very  easy to test, something like select count(*) from accounts  WHERE username = 'testuser' AND password = 'testpass'; if it gets you 0 results, then there is nothing to update...

Comment: I think you're using a reserved word (PASSWORD). Try to wrap all column and table names in brackets anyway to rule it out. `UPDATE [accounts] 
SET [displayname] = 'test', [member] = '5'
WHERE [username] = 'testuser' AND [password]= 'testpass'`

Comment: @equisde, does MySQL really support square brackets for delimited identifiers?

Comment: As far as I know MySQL does not support square brackets. It use single quotes instead.

Comment: I'd even go with back-ticks.

Comment: `"As far as I know MySQL does not support square brackets. It use single quotes instead"`I meant backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically no rows match your given query, check the contents of your table. There's no 'testpass' for the password col in that row.

Comment: That's what I thought, but here is example I tried: https://i.imgur.com/ctx7og1.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote reserved words to avoid using reserved words like 'password'.

```
UPDATE accounts SET displayname = 'test', 
member = '5' WHERE username = 'testuser' 
AND `password` = 'testpass'
```

Comment: Error in mysql syntax

Comment: It's slightly different in MySQL. Reserved keyword must be quoted. Answer updated.

Comment: If that `UPDATE` statement doesn't update your record means that at least one of the conditions is not matching your records. Furthermore, if using `LIKE` condition and `%` wildcard your record is updated, most likely is that you've blank spaces into these fields.

Comment: I don't know of any DBMS where you use single quotes for alias names. Single quotes are for string literals. Double quotes are for aliases according to standard SQL. MySQL uses backticksinstead; I don't know whether double quotes also work.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right. I confused quotes with backticks. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

I see your conditions matched your Condition query. Have you tried checking the value of the fields? Check if there are no spaces.

Comment: @user5226582: I think this *is* the answer. There is no match, because there is a blank or something else in the password string that the OP isn't aware of.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should not be in the answer section. If you have enough privilege to make comments, you can comment   otherwise as long as you don't have a correct and accurate answer please refrain from using answer button to make comments